# Widowed pilcrow (non printable ¶ at line begining) in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice, typography

I'm struggling with widowed pilcrows (i.e. non-printable ¶ at beginning of lines). This happens only in footnotes, on page-breaks, and it adds a space between the footnote's rule and the first expected footnote on new page.

[image]

Is there a way to batch remove these, and prevent them from happening again ?

What I've tried :

- selecting previous footnote and CTRL+M it (doesn't work)
- in footnotes style, making them non-breakbable (works, but I actually want them to be breakable !)
- removing them manually (works, is exhausting on a 600p. document)
- inserting a nonbreakable space at the end of all footnotes (does not work)

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, if that helps.